# Method chaining in class in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, this, return-value, chaining

I am new in javascript. And I'm trying to figure out how classes work. 
I have this piece of code:

```
class TestObject {
  constructor(initialNumber) {
    this.result = initialNumber;
}
  add(number) {
    this.result += number;
    return this;
  }
}

const value = new TestObject(7)
    .add(2)
    .add(3);
console.log(value)
```

Value returns like this `{result: 12}` But I need it to be just the integer `12`. Is there any way to fix this by making changes **only in the class body**?

Comment: Just to Check, is this a homework question? It's fine if it is but should be upfront if thats the case.

Comment: There's no way to do that dynamically. Obviously if the code would always be the same and you must absolutely find a way to do this then you could track how many times `add` got invoked and return the value only on the second call, but that would just be a solution that works in this very case and wouldn't make sense unless it was a challenge.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, it's a homework question. All I can do is implementing methods and constructor in class. I also have other methods with binary operations. I can't touch what's outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

As your `value` variable is an instance of `TestObject`, so you can use

`console.log(value.result);`

```js
class TestObject {
  constructor(initialNumber) {
    this.result = initialNumber;
}
  add(number) {
    this.result += number;
    return this;
  }
}

const value = new TestObject(7)
    .add(2)
    .add(3);
    
console.log(value.result);
```

Comment: ...which **isn't** a change "only in the class body."

Answer (score 0):

> ...by making changes **only in the class body**?

No. You'd have to change something outside it as well, because your `add` method returns an object, not a number. So something has to say "I want a number instead please."

If you add a `valueOf` method to your class:

```
valueOf() {
    return this.result;
}
```

...then the thing outside the class body could be just a `+`:

```
console.log(+value);
```

...but that's still outside the class body.

Live example:

```js
class TestObject {
  constructor(initialNumber) {
    this.result = initialNumber;
}
  add(number) {
    this.result += number;
    return this;
  }
  
  valueOf() {
    return this.result;
  }
}

const value = new TestObject(7)
    .add(2)
    .add(3);
console.log(+value);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you returning the result from your method so the value will be a object **{result:12}**, If you want to see the execution and debug it, please add `debugger;` to any line you need you can understand what is getting;

```
    class TestObject {
      constructor(initialNumber) {
        this.result = initialNumber;
    }
      add(number) {
        this.result += number;
        debugger;
        return this;
      }
    }

    const value = new TestObject(7)
        .add(2)
        .add(3);
     debugger;
    console.log(value)
```

with the code what you wrote, if you change the `Console.log(value.result)` you will get the desired result .